# View using "Display links" not showing links when teaser view mode is used

Tags: 7, views

I have the following format setting in my view: 
[image: Views format setting]

This doesn't work when the "View mode" is "Teaser", but works fine when it's set to "Full content".

There is a custom template file for this node type, but it contains the standard

```
<?php print render($content['links']); ?>
```

Anyone know what the root cause might be?